# AES Encryption in windows phone 8

Tags: c#, encryption, windows-phone-8, cryptography, aes

I am trying to do AES Encryption in my windows phone8 app.

I searched a lot, but couldn't get a clear view to do so.

Can anybody give me link that gives the clear example of implementing AES Encryption ni WP8 App.

What i need to do is,

1)I need to pass key, initial vector, and value as strings.

2)need to encrypt that string in any format of AES Encryption, and finally need to get the encrypted value as string.

Can anybody help me.

am using [this example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aesmanaged.aspx) and using UTF8 encoding for key, and Iv

`myAes.Key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("terr!f!cp@ssw0rdw!thonetw!st!n!t");
 myAes.IV = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("1234567890987654");`

and after encoding to convert the bytes of encrypted value to string am using ToBase64 convertion

`afterText.Text = Convert.ToBase64String(encrypted);`

here i need to tell my back end team, what the exact encryption am using here, am not sure about what is happening here, Can you please tell me whats that exact encryption happening here.

Thank you.

Comment: key, IV, encrypted value are all `byte[]`. Any attempt to threat then as `string` will result in failure. Perhaps this is why you did not find any example?

Comment: 1) Use either Base64 or Hex encoding for key, IV and ciphertext 2) Use UTF-8 encoding for the plaintext

Comment: Note that AES keys should use the full range within the specified bytes. If you use only a subset you cannot really claim to have performed AES encryption at the specified bitlevel. Normally a method like [PBKDF2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes.aspx) is used to convert a password to a key.

Answer (score 2):

The [CryptographicBuffer Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/apps/windows.security.cryptography.cryptographicbuffer) is your friend:

- Use Hex or Base64 encoding for binary values you want to represent as strings. This includes Key, IV and ciphertext
- Use UTF-8 for text you want to turn to bytes.