# AES implementation for Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, security, encryption, windows-phone-8.1

I am searching for AES implementation for windows phone 8.1 but i am unable to find it anywhere.In [Microsoft's](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aesmanaged.aspx) official documentation `System.Security.Cryptography` is used which is [not compatible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24381079/windows-phone-8-1-system-security-cryptography-doesnt-exist) with windows phone 8.1 and the alternative [Windows.Security.cryptography](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.security.cryptography.aspx) doesn't have the required classes.

Note : There is [another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18913175/aes-encryption-in-windows-phone-8) question regarding the same problem but again the solution provided is not working for Windows Phone 8.1.

Comment: Have you checked whether [inferno](http://securitydriven.net/inferno/) works on windows phone?

Answer (score 0):

Windows Phone supports various flavours of AES. See the [`SymmetricAlgorithmKeyNames` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.security.cryptography.core.symmetricalgorithmnames.aspx) and related [`SymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.security.cryptography.core.symmetrickeyalgorithmprovider.openalgorithm.aspx).